# SwiftUI: How can I avoid white space beside a sticky (pinned) header in a list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list with a coloured background:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { i in
        Section(header:
            ZStack {
                Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Text("Header \(i)")
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        ) {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { j in
                Text("Item \(i)-\(j)")
                    .listRowBackground(Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            }
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.background(Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

All is fine as long as it is running in portrait mode:
[image: List in portrait mode]

However, in landscape mode, when I start to scroll down, there is a bright space on the left and on the right of the sticky (pinned) header. And I have no idea how to get rid of it:
[image: List in landscape mode]

In my real app it looks even worse, since there I have a toolbar above. I assume what I can see there is a blurred white area with the yellow background shining through. However, I would like to have it orange here as well.

Any hints how to solve this are highly appreciated.

Comment: Was answered, but the asker refuses to use the solution and add complexity to the swiftui code.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you are fighting against the "apple way" of styling the grouped lists. If you have a custom way, simple don't use the Apple's way:

```swift
        List {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { i in
                    ForEach(1...50, id: \.self) { j in
                        if (j % 5) == 0 { // not this, but a way to detect this is a header and not a item
                            Text("Header \(i)")
                                .listRowBackground(Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                        } else {
                            Text("Item \(i)-\(j)")
                                .listRowBackground(Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                        }
                    }
                
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .background(Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

[image: representation]

Comment: I want to do it in the apple way, only with different colours... When I check the view hierarchy in Xcode, I see there is a white CALayer behind my pinned header. Probably I "only" have to change the color of this layer. But how?

As far as I see, doing it my way would mean to use ScrollView and LazyVStack with pinnedViews for the headers. Probably I could handle this as well, but I do not want to re-invent the whole list stuff, only because of a colour error in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack which solves my issue. I'm not really happy with it, but at least it works: inside the ZStack I use now a GeometryReader, which colours a bigger area than the one provided by the list:

```
List {
    ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { i in
        Section(header:
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Rectangle()
                        .path(in: CGRect(x: -proxy.size.width/2, y: 0, width: 2 * proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height))
                        .fill(Color.orange)
                }
                Text("Header \(i)")
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        ) {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { j in
                Text("Item \(i)-\(j)")
                    .listRowBackground(Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            }
        }
    }
}
.listStyle(.plain)
.background(Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```